# How are spark executors created?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to understand how spark executors are being launched and by who. My understanding is Driver will be in charge of everything, especially `SparkSession.builder` will be creating connections to cluster manager and executors. It seems the builder will also configure executors. Does this mean the executors are launched by driver during `builder.getOrCreate()`?

```
builder.config("spark.executor.cores", 5)
builder.config("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this , you need to understand what a cluster manager does. In a nutshell (Here I have considered YARN as a cluster manager) ,

1. YARN works through a Resource Manager  and Node Managers which runs on all the nodes. The Resource Manager manages the resources used across the cluster and the Node Manager launches and monitors the containers. Scheduler and Application Manager are two components of the Resource Manager.
2. Scheduler : Scheduling is performed based on the requirement of resources by the applications. YARN provides few schedulers to choose from and they are Fair and Capacity Scheduler.
3. Application Manager: It manages the running of Application Master in a cluster and on the failure of the Application Master Container, it helps in restarting it. Also, it bears the responsibility of accepting the submission of the jobs.
4. Node Manager : It is responsible for the execution of the task in each data node. Chiefly it manages the application containers which are assigned by the Resource Manager. The Node Manager starts the containers by creating the container processes which are requested and it also kills the containers as asked by the Resource Manager
5. Application Master : It monitors the execution of tasks and also manages the lifecycle of applications running on the cluster. An individual Application Master gets associated with a job when it is submitted to the framework. Its chief responsibility is to negotiate the resources from the Resource Manager. It works with the Node Manager to monitor and execute the tasks

Now when you will submit a spark application to a cluster

1. First Yarn launches the container for running application master in one of the data nodes
2. If you submit the spark job in cluster mode , your driver program also will be running in the same container of application master. In client mode it will be on your edge node. This container for driver will have the resource requirements which is given through spark.driver.memory and spark.driver.cores
3. Once driver starts running , Application master will negotiate for other executor resource needs with resource manager and resource manager utilizes schedulers and node managers for launching the respective executor containers in available worker nodes.

I have written a blog on this sometimes back, it may help you to understand it in detail:

http://pathirippilly.blogspot.com/2018/12/understanding-spark-architecture-in.html

Also lots of excellent materials are available on internet as well.